# Traverse file system and move files

Tags: bash

I need to write a script that will go into a list of directories and then move files of cretin file types into a other directory.

With the code bellow I am able to iterate over all the folders in a directory and print their names. I figure that I will need to cd in and out of these folders.

```
for d in */
do
  echo "$d"
done
```

The code bellow will iterate over each .png file and move it to the desired directory.

```
for file in *.png
 do
    mv "$file" /desired/directory
done
```

now for some reason when I put the second block of code in the first I get this output:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘*.png’: No such file or directory
```

How do I get it to traverse and move each file? I would like to place this script at the root of the /search/directory/

Comment: How whould you input all the directory names from which you want to move all `.png` files? a file having the name of directories?

Comment: Well in this case all the directories are named recup_Dir.1-976 so you could iterate through them. But I wanted it to just happen. The second loop in my code will move all files that end with .png I figured there might be a way to do this with directories. The first loop is able to iterate through the directories and print their names. But that's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in */
do
 mv - n *.png /desired/directory/
done
```

There will be an issue with files with the same name as the first will be write and following will not as the -n tag is set otherwise the second would overwrite the first and loss of the first file.  This will not copy any files in sub sub directory

Scratch that use

```
find /search/directory/ -inane "*.png" -exce mv -n {} /desired/directory/ \;
```

But will have same problem with same name files

If you want duplactes named file eg. Pic.png 1Pic.png 2Pic.png ect

```
dup=1
find /search/directory/ -inane "*.png" -exce mv -n {} /desired/directory/ \;
while(find /search/directory/ -inane "*.png" | wc -l !=0)
  find /search/directory/ -inane "*.png" -exce mv -n {} /desired/directory/$dup$(basename {}) \;
    dup++
done
```

This loop will not break out if /desired/directory is in the /search/directory.  I did this off the top of my head the only part I'm worried about is the while condition might need the find | wc in brackets maybe with $ in front
This could be further improved by error checking and have .png /search/directory /desired/directory as arguments

Comment: as far as I could tell none of these solutions worked. I would like to place this script at the root of a directory and then just run it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /full/path/to/recup_Dir.{1..976}; do
mv "$dir"/*.png /full/path/to/desired/directory/
done
```

Here we are looping through the source directories and then copying all the `.png` files from those directories to the desired directory. As we are using the absolute paths here, you can run this script from any location.